# Nginx ingress config not being generated correctly in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, fastcgi

Looks like my NGINX is trying to connect to the php-fpm container via HTTP instead of fascgi.
When I try to connect to the php-fpm container manually via fastcgi, thats the response:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.4
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And thats the log in the php-fpm container:

```
127.0.0.1 -  29/Mar/2023:16:16:15 +0000 "GET index.php" 404
```

Which means the fcgi connection is working, and the fpm is listening on 9000 via fastcgi.

But when I try to connect via NGINX, I receive 502 and thats the log on nginx container:
`recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream`

```
2023/03/28 22:27:37 [error] 31#31: *423 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.116.0.3, server: homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.244.0.24:9000/favicon.ico", host: "homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br", referrer: "https://homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br/"
10.116.0.3 - - [28/Mar/2023:22:27:37 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "https://homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

So nginx IS connecting to the container, in the right port, and it is able to make a get request, but I strongly believe its using HTTP instead of fasCGI, and thats why is not working.
ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: prod-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: <email>
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: prod-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: homolog-fcgi
data:
  SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/var/www/html/public/index.php"
  DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/var/www/html/public"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-fcgi
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: prod-issuer
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: homolog-fcgi
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls: 
    - hosts: 
      - homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br
      secretName: homolog-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: main-api-service
            port:
              number: 9000
```

what config kubernetes is generating:

```
upstream default-ingress-fcgi-homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br-main-api-service-9000 {
    zone default-ingress-fcgi-homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br-main-api-service-9000 256k;
    random two least_conn;
    
    server 10.244.0.12:9000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s max_conns=0;   
}

server {
    
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secrets/default-homolog-tls-secret;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secrets/default-homolog-tls-secret;

    server_tokens on;

    server_name homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br;

    set $resource_type "ingress";
    set $resource_name "ingress-fcgi";
    set $resource_namespace "default";

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    }
    
    location / {
        set $service "main-api-service";
                
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_send_timeout 60s;
        client_max_body_size 1m;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering on;
        
        proxy_pass http://default-ingress-fcgi-homolog.main-api.fretegestao.com.br-main-api-service-9000;
            
    }
    
}
```

I dont totally understand nginx config, but I think the problem is the `proxy_pass` should be `fastcgi_pass`. What is wrong with my ingress file? why isnt it using fastCGI?